# Group cohomology of groups with one relation

Tags: group-cohomology

> If a group $G$ is defined by a single relation $R$, where $R$ = $Q^q$ for $q$ maximal, and if $K$ is any left $G$-module, then

> $H^2(G,K) \cong K/(\frac{\partial R}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial R}{\partial x_m})$
> and
> $H^n(G,K) \cong 0, \ \ n>2$

This is [Corollory 11.2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969440?seq=3), in a paper from R.C. Lyndon.

What does maximal mean here, and, is there anything known about $H^1(G,K)$ and $H^0(G,K)$? Here I think for instance of a group $G$ having a presentation of the form $\langle x_1\lvert x_1^2\rangle $.

Thank you for your assistance and help.